# negative keywords for on-page optimization?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, technical-seo, tags

I have frequently used negative keywords in a PPC environment. However, I'm curious if anyone has pursued applying negative keywords organically for additional on-page optimization.

For general example: You have a page on 'rehab' with semantically related keywords for rehab types already optimized for sub-topics. I.e. drug, alcohol, etc with internal linking.
You don't want to appear in search results for 'physical therapy rehab'.
DESIRED GOAL: Add negative keywords for 'physical therapy' and unrelated keywords / unwanted traffic.

Do any out-of-the-box brains out there think it's doable? I've found nothing so far supporting my strategy theory thus far.

I've implemented the following:

Prioritized content by identifying and tagging core pages/post (Yoast Cornerstone Pages/Posts)
Keyword optimization using focus keywords and semantically related keywords.
Added internal linking for core pages and posts.
Optimized headings, meta description, URL slug, categorization, and image alt attribute data.
I'd LOVE your feedback and thoughts on implementation methodologies. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thats the difference with SEO, its the search engines that decide what a page will rank for rather than you paying per click.

The more links you build to a page the more important Google will consider it to be and therefore the more semantic variants you'll appear in the SERPS for.

If you want to not appear for phrases then the only way is not to mention any variant of them which in reality defeats the object of it.

I run a recruitment site, and we offer part-time CFO's a get a lot of random traffic from people searching for phrases like Part-Time jobs near me, it's just one of those things with SEO/SEM.

Answer (score 0):

Google analyses the content of the page, and how relevant the url, meta tags (such as title) and h1 etc. are relevant to it.  The higher the relevancy the better.

So, trying to fool it will only reduce you indexability/ranking. Because the content will not be relevant with your "keywords".